# Increase the size of Touch UI Dialog

Tags: touch, aem

```
Is there a way to increase the size of the touch UI Dialog so that all of my tabs won't wrap as shown below?
```

[image]

Is there a way to increase the size of the touch UI Dialog so that all of my tabs won't wrap. Below  is an example of the dialog that I currently have in place. This is a well  known issue from what I've researched online but I haven't seen any examples on how to solve this issue.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
 sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
 <content
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
    <layout
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
        type="nav"/>
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <Ice
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Ice"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
            path="ttue/components/page/page/cq:dialog/ICe"/>
        <Jungle
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Jungle"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
             path="ttue/components/page/page/cq:dialog/Jungle"/>
        <Fire
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Fire"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
             path="ttue/components/page/page/cq:dialog/Fire"/>
        <Church
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Church"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
             path="ttue/components/page/page/cq:dialog/Church"/>
        <Food
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Food"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
             path="ttue/components/page/page/cq:dialog/Food"/>
        <Basketball
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Basketball"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
            path="ttue/components/page/page/cq:dialog/basketball"/>
    </items>
</content>
```

Comment: Can you kindly update your question with the dialog xml as well?

Comment: Okay, I just added the dialog

Comment: This question might can help you : http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__2ect-how_do_wesetheight.html

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($, $document) {
    "use strict";

    function increaseSize(){
       // $(".coral-FixedColumn-column").css("height", "50rem");
       //$(".coral-FixedColumn-column").css("width", "50rem");
       $(".coral-dialog").css("height", "50rem");
       $(".coral-dialog").css("width", "50rem");
    }

    $document.on("dialog-ready", function() {
        increaseSize();
    });

})($, $(document));
```

"coral-dialog" is a sample class name please modify accordingly.
Read this for more details:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/index.html